# Calculating coordinates of two GPS points whose line through them is perpendicular to two other GPS points

Tags: python, coordinates, distance, gps, haversine

Given two GPS points A and B, I would like to compute the GPS coordinates A1 and A2.       [A1A2] forms a segment perpendicular to segment [AB].
[image: gps]
For this, I start to compute M1, which is the midpoint of [AB] and should be the midpoint of [A1A2].
The distance `[A1M1] = [M1A2] = d`
My approach consists of finding the distance from A to B using the haversine formula.

```
from haversine import haversine

A = (lat1, lon1)
B = (lat2, lon2)

dist = haversine(A, B)
```

Then I get half of it.

```
half_dist = dist/2
```

After that, I find the GPS coordinate `M1` located on segment [AB], which distance `|AM1| = half_dist`
For that, I use the approach proposed [on this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349458/python-for-finding-the-gps-coordinates-of-a-point-x-distance-between-2-other-gps).

```
from geographiclib.geodesic import Geodesic
#Define the ellipsoid
geod = Geodesic.WGS84

#Solve the Inverse problem
inv = geod.Inverse(A[0],A[1],B[0],B[1])
azi1 = inv['azi1']

#Solve the Direct problem
dir = geod.Direct(A[0],A[1],azi1,half_dist)
M1 = (dir['lat2'],dir['lon2'])
```

My difficulty starts here. I don't know how to go on to calculate the coordinates of points A1 and A2 given the distance d.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you use coordinates as if in Cartesian? Since the area you are working in is very small, the error will be too small to be ignored, unless you're working with millimeter precision.

Comment: Thank you @KadirŞahbaz, I will do that, a gap of about 1 meter will not be a problem for me.